# CSS - how to get position: absolute; to work well with different screen sizes

Tags: css, screen

If I want an element to be positioned at a certain position on my screen I can use:

```
position: absolute;
top: 614px;
left: 215px;
```

And on my screen this works perfect, the element is right where I want it to be. However if I use a bigger screen it is all wrong and if I use a really small screen you might have to scroll to see the element at all. How can you fix this?
I've tried researching and I figured this was quite a normal issue but I haven't really found anything helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position absolute css works by placing something absolutely with respect to the parent element. If a parent element doesn't exit it will default all the way to the `html` element. Basically in short this means if your parent changes your absolute positioning changes.

It's a better idea to use percentages if you want it to be responsive. You can also use media queries to adjust positions as required.

```css
  .my-absolute-px{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
    
    .my-absolute-percent{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 45%;
    }
```

```html
  
    
    <div class="my-absolute-px">Some px content</div>
    <div class="my-absolute-percent">Some % content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea you could use percentages, that is so much better in every way. :)

Comment: Cheers and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to stick the element to the bottom-right edge of the window? Then just use `bottom:0` and `right:0` respecitvely:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Or, if you want to position it in the middle, apply 50%:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but that's not really what I'm looking for. I want to position the element somewhere in the middle of the screen, not in the corner.